# Angular 2 Observable and Promise callback unit testing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angular, jasmine, rxjs

I have a method in an Angular 2 service, which gets all the details of a specific user account - the one that's logged in - and returns an Observable.

*(I am using AngularFire2 for authentication, for what it's worth)*

As you can see, the `getData` method is using the `getAuth` method which returns the authentication state (as an observable), which in turn is used by the `getToken` method (which returns a Promise) to get the token which is used to populate the `Authorization` headers and do an http request. *(I do understand that my code might require refactoring, and I would appreciate any feedback on that)*

```
getData(): Observable<IData> {
    let authHeaders = new Headers();

    return Observable.create((o: Observer<IData>) => {
        this.getAuth().subscribe((authState: IState) => {
            this.getToken(authState).then(token => {
                /* ...
                 * Do things with that token, call an http service etc.
                 */ ...
                authHeaders.set('Authorization', token);

                this.http.get('myendpoint/', {
                    headers: this.authHeaders
                })
                .map((response: Response) => response.json())
                .map((data: IData) => {
                    o.next(data);
                });
            })
            .catch((error: Error) => {
                Observable.throw(new Error(`Error: ${error}`));
            });
        });
    });
}
```

I am new to unit testing, and have been trying to test this method, but I still cannot cover the `.catch` of a Promise inside that method.

Here's what my unit test looks like:

```
describe('Service: UserDataService', () => {
    let mockHttp: Http;
    let service: UserDataService;
    let getAuthSpy: jasmine.Spy;
    let getTokenSpy: jasmine.Spy;

    beforeEach(() => {
        mockHttp = { get: null } as Http;

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [
                { provide: Http, useValue: mockHttp },
                AngularFire,
                UserDataService,
            ]
        });

        service = new UserDataService(AngularFire, mockHttp);

        spyOn(mockHttp, 'get').and.returnValue(Observable.of({
            json: () => {
                "nickname": "MockNickname"
            }
        }));

        getAuthSpy = spyOn(service, 'getAuth').and.returnValue(Observable.of({
          "auth": {
            "uid": "12345"
        }));

        getTokenSpy = spyOn(service, 'getToken').and.returnValue(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve('test promise response');
        }));
    });

    describe('getLead', () => {
        beforeEach(() => {
            spyOn(service, 'getLead').and.callThrough();
        });

        it('should return an object of user data and set the dataStore.userEmail if state exists', () => {
            service.getLead().subscribe(res => {
                expect(res).toEqual(jasmine.objectContaining({
                    nickname: 'MockNickname'
                }));
            });

            expect(service.getLead).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });

        it('should throw, if no authState is provided', () => {
            getAuthSpy.and.returnValue(Observable.of(false));

            service.getLead();

            expect(service.getLead).toThrow();
        });

        it('should throw, if getToken() fails to return a token', () => {
            getTokenSpy.and.returnValue(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                reject('test error response');
            }));

            /*
             * This is where I am getting lost
             */

            service.getLead();

            expect(service.getLead).toThrow();
        });
    });
});
```

From what I understand I have to somehow make that Promise from `getToken` reject, and test to see if my observable will throw.

Any help or feedback greatly appreciated.

Comment: `spyOn(...).and.returnValue(Observable.throw(...).toPromise())`? You could make this a bit more linear with `Observable.map`, going step by step rather than increasing nesting, converting `fromPromise` and `toPromise` as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use either `jasmine` nor AngularFire2 so I can't tell what exactly you have to do but from you code it's obvious that `this.getToken(authState)` returns a `Promise`.

Question is from what library this `Promise` class comes from (aka what polyfill you're using).

As far as I know implementations of [Promises/A](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises/A) should wrap callback calls with try - catch, so if your callback in `then(...)` throws an exception that the Promise will propagate to `catch()`. So I guess you could fake response from `this.http.get('myendpoint/')` with some malformed JSON that would cause an error at `response.json()`.

Second thing is the inner callback for `catch()`:

```
.catch((error: Error) => {
    Observable.throw(new Error(`Error: ${error}`));
});
```

This does literally nothing. There's no return statement and `Observable.throw()` needs to appear inside Observable chain to do something. Note that this `.catch()` method comes from your Promise class and not from Observable.

If you want it to actually propagate the error to Observers then you have to explicitly call:

```
.catch((error: Error) => {
    o.error(error);
});
```

Maybe if the error bubbled up to the `Observable.create()` it would be passed to the Observer as well, I'm not sure about this.

Answer (score 2):

I had I similar issue, then I've used Observable.from:

```
spyOn(service, 'function').and.returnValue(Observable.fromPromise(Promise.reject({})));
```

You return the error inside Promise.reject